# Can I store data contents of a json file in a data structure in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am newby in Flutter. Is it possible to store the contents of a json file in a suitable data structure which only needs constant time to find a specific entry? If yes, how can the json file be read and what data structure is suitable? I suppose a hash table should only need constant time to find a specific element?

I am newby and have absolutely no idea, if it can work at all.

Answer (score 0):

JSON files are really common. Usually they are converted into maps. Maps have constant lookup time. Dart has methods for decoding (JSON string -> Map) and encoding (Map -> JSON String).

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html

Comment: Could you give a short example how this code: const jsonArray = '''
  [{"text": "foo", "value": 1, "status": true},
   {"text": "bar", "value": 2, "status": false}]
''';

final List<dynamic> dataList = jsonDecode(jsonArray);
print(dataList[0]); // {text: foo, value: 1, status: true}
print(dataList[1]); // {text: bar, value: 2, status: false}

final item = dataList[0];
print(item['text']); // foo
print(item['value']); // 1
print(item['status']); // false  can be implemented in a dart file? When I copy this code, I get the message the the code is unreachable.

Comment: Create another question for this if needed but this is pretty basic stuff and I would advice you to look into beginner tutorials first. Good luck!